# Trouble with jQuery validate rules for Form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

Hello I am trying to use jQuery Validation ,

Basically i have a form , where certain elements are required no matter what,

but then i have other fields that are only required is a checkbox is selected

i am using jQuery Validation
  
here is a link to [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21)

Here is my form

```
<form action="http://www.funnytennisstories.com/save-story.php" method="POST" name="story-form" id="storyForm">
<fieldset>
    <label for="Your Story">Your Story</label>
    <textarea class="required" name="your-story" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    <label for="free-wrist-band">Check the box to receive a free tennis wristband &nbsp;  </label>
    <input id="free-wrist-band-check-box" name="free-wrist-band" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="address">Address</label><input id="address" class="txtClass shipping" name="address" type="text" >
    <input type="submit" name="story-post" value="Post Your Story"/>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

So i have cut it down quite a bit, but basically if `free-wrist-band-check-box` is selected i should have to put in address text, but if it is not checked i should not have to put in any text

Here is the javascript i have written, but if the checkbox is selected it does not work

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#storyForm").validate({
    debug:true,
       rules: {
         shipping: {
             required: $("#free-wrist-band-check-box:checked")
           }
       }
    });
});
```

Debug is also not showing in firebug lite(and the inspect element tool) on chrome and inspector on safari

Any Ideas guys

Comment: What form validation jQuery extension do you use? (Google gave me a lot of results for "jQuery Validation".) Or do you want to write your own validation tool?

Comment: edited the post, near the top

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

```
$('#free-wrist-band-check-box').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) $("#address").rules("add", "required");
    else $("#address").rules("remove", "required");
});
```

So the `address text box` will be required only if the `checkbox` is checked.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/SeWXp/8/)